# Pyperclip Module failed on Android

Tags: python, kivy, pyperclip

The pyperclip module is not letting my android app launch. It closes as soon as I run the app on my phone. It works fine on Windows though.

Using Kivy to code the application
Using Buildozer to pack an APK

```
import pyperclip as syscopy

syscopy.copy("Hi There")
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. You need to provide all the details and 
mention the issue clearly what exactly you want. Please refer the
[ask] link for more detail and update your question accordingly.

Comment: I think pyperclip probably just doesn't work on Android, where interacting with the clipboard requires java api calls. You can do this using pyjnius, but I don't have an example.

Comment: I couldn't get my head around with pyjnius. However, I used kivy.core and imported Clipboard to solve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same Problem. Do you have a log.txt from your build? If so, check whether it is a Permission Error or not. If it is a Permission Error, you have to get the code in to a try and except e.g:

```
import pyperclip as syscopy

try:
  syscopy.copy("Hi There")
except(PermissionError):
  print("There is an error!")
```

Hope it will work.